# How to solve this DNS issue?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, webserver, domain

I have an Apache web server (on a Windows VPS) and a while ago I registered a .tk domain. Then I picked (ns1.afraid.org) and (ns2.afraid.org) as my name servers and I pointed mydomain.tk to 22.22.22.22/script (the website location e.x). Now when someone types mydomain.tk he goes to 22.22.22.22/script but the problem is in the address bar it still shows 22.22.22.22/script not mydomain.tk. How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which Record did you use to point to the IP?

Comment: I just checked that. It's Web Redirect, it doesn't let me to use "A" record because of "/script" part of my address.

Comment: You have to use an "A" record and then create a virtual-host on your VPS

Comment: Yeah, But how? I have for example 5 directories and I can't just copy /script to the main directory. How to point /scirpt1 /scirpt2 and... to specific domains?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Comment: Yes, I just found in other resources. Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a web-redirect, the browser is obliged to tell the user what's going on. Redirects are &mbash; by nature — an interruption in the flow of web-surfing. DNS, on the other hand, is a little more trusted: it's considered just another way to refer to the same thing.

Assuming that you do not control server 22.22.22.22, there is no perfect solution — unless it's a service that specifically allows for you to use your own domain name. However, you could try embedding your 22.22.22.22/script website in an iframe, rather than redirecting:

```
<iframe width="100%" height=1"00%" src="http://22.22.22.22/script">
```

This will break bookmarks, and impede url-based navigation.

Comment: If you *do* control the 22.22.22.22 host, there is a way to do it, but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Yeah, I have the VPS. Isn't there any .htaccess solution?

Comment: No good one at least.